# Winium Driver is not starting using Java

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, winium

I am testing Excel file using winium and TestNg. When I am manually starting winium driver that time the test cases are working properly. When I am trying to start Winium service from java that time it is giving me problem to start the Winium Driver.
Code is as belows :

```
package testcases;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriverService;
import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.collections.Lists;
import HelperClass.ExcelFiles;

public class WiniumRunner {

private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    File file = new File(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString());
    String winiumDriverPath = file + "\\Winium.Desktop.Driver\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe";

    System.out.println("Starting service of Winium Desktop Driver");
    WiniumDriverService service = new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new
            File(winiumDriverPath)).usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true).withSilent(false).buildDesktopService();

    service.start(); // Build and Start a Winium Driver service
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("Started service of Winium Desktop Driver");

    String cDateTime = "";
    Date date = new Date();      
    cDateTime = cDateTime + (sdf.format(date));   
    cDateTime = file+"\\Reports\\Mockito_Test_Reports\\";

    ExcelFiles EF= new ExcelFiles();
    EF.createExcelFile();
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setOutputDirectory(cDateTime);

    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    System.out.println("**********Test Report Location   :"+file+"\\src\\props\\testng2.xml");
    suites.add(file+"\\src\\test\\java\\testcases\\testng2.xml");
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
    process.waitFor();
    process.destroy();
}
}
```

I am getting below Exception :

```
Starting service of Winium Desktop Driver
Starting Windows Desktop Driver on port 9999

16:53:39 [DEBUG] Waiting for a connection...
16:53:40 [DEBUG] ACCEPTED REQUEST GET /status HTTP/1.1
16:53:40 [INFO] COMMAND status
{}
16:53:40 [DEBUG] RESPONSE:
OK: {
 "sessionId": "AwesomeSession",
 "status": 0,
 "value": {
"build": {
  "version": "1.2.0.0"
},
"os": {
  "arch": "x64",
  "name": "windows",
  "version": "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0"
   }
  }
}
 16:53:40 [DEBUG] Client closed

 16:53:40 [DEBUG] Waiting for a connection...
 Started service of Winium Desktop Driver

  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
 (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
  log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
  16:53:47 [DEBUG] ACCEPTED REQUEST POST /session HTTP/1.1
  16:53:47 [INFO] COMMAND newSession

        16:53:47 [INFO] COMMAND newSession
    {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "app": null
      }
    }
    16:53:47 [DEBUG] RESPONSE:
    OK: {
      "sessionId": "AwesomeSession",
      "status": 13,
      "value": {
        "error": "unknown error",
        "stacktrace": "   at Winium.Cruciatus.Application..ctor(String 
 executableFilePath)\r\n   at  Winium.Desktop.Driver.CommandExecutors.NewSessionExecutor.InitializeApplication(Boolean debugDoNotDeploy)\r\n   at Winium.Desktop.Driver.CommandExecutors.NewSessionExecutor.DoImpl()\r\n   at Winium.Desktop.Driver.CommandExecutors.CommandExecutorBase.Do()",
        "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: executableFilePath"
      }
    }
    16:53:47 [DEBUG] Client closed

    16:53:47 [DEBUG] Waiting for a connection...
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: executableFilePath (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 208 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06'
    System info: host: 'DESKTOP-5A26C5Q', ip: '192.168.225.198', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
        at org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver.<init>(WiniumDriver.java:84)
        at testcases.UserRegistrationForm.intiallizeTest(UserRegistrationForm.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
        at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
        at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:619)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:609)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:580)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
        at testcases.WiniumRunner.main(WiniumRunner.java:50)
```

I am not able to debug the Error. If someone can suggest Changes in code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is `Started service of Winium Desktop Driver` printed?

Comment: I have updated stacktrace @Boris

Comment: And where is `Starting Windows Desktop Driver` coming from? It's in the logs, but not present in the code.

Comment: It is the statement from Winium Driver it is coming from driver .

Comment: The exception is thrown from the [Application.cs](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Cruciatus/blob/09ff49c971a6bdb4c18ddfecdd88508439519187/src/Winium.Cruciatus/Application.cs#L38) class constructor.

Comment: The executable file path which is null is created [here](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/blob/bc4999ecc5c452839058a71054c685db8854f5c9/src/Winium.Desktop.Driver/CommandExecutors/NewSessionExecutor.cs#L40).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see the exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: executableFilePath
```

is because `executableFilePath` is null in the [Application](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Cruciatus/blob/09ff49c971a6bdb4c18ddfecdd88508439519187/src/Winium.Cruciatus/Application.cs#L38) constructor. As a result `DesiredCapabilities` is not set:

```
{
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "app": null
  }
}
```

According to the [README](https://github.com/2gis/Winium/tree/master/java) you should set `DesktopOptions` before creating the instance of the `WebDriver` class:

```java
DesktopOptions options = new DesktopOptions();
options.setApplicationPath("pathToWindowsApplication");
options.setDebugConnectToRunningApp(true);
WiniumDriverService service = new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File(winiumDriverPath)).usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true).withSilent(false).buildDesktopService();
WiniumDriver driver = new WiniumDriver(service, options);
service.start(); // Build and Start a Winium Driver service
```

Comment: Still I am getting same exception

Comment: What happens if you add `options.setDebugConnectToRunningApp(true);` ?

Comment: Issue got resolved. the application path from another file is null because of that it is giving me exception.